# Pytorch nn embeddings dimension size?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

What is the correct dimension size for nn embeddings in Pytorch? I'm doing batch training.

I'm just a little confused with what the dimensions of "self.embeddings" in the code below are supposed to be when I get "shape"?

```
self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
```

Comment: Do you mean what is the shape of self.embedding?

Comment: @JibinMathew yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of the `self.embedding` will be `[sentence_length, batch_size, embedding_dim]`

where `sentence_length` is the length of inputs in each batch.

Comment: Just a follow-up question, in the "forward" function of the model, if I want to pass the self.embeddings to an nn.linear layer, how do I do it? It says "Expected input batch_size (4) to match target batch_size (32)." Should I use "sum"? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you post it as separate question with code, so that it give better idea and helps others

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302229/pytorch-shapes-do-not-match